# AsyncTask without thread

Tags: android, android-asynctask, android-jobscheduler, jobservice

i am using AsyncTask for some part of my code but i have a jobSchedulerIntentService and i want to send data to server and receive some responses. i want to do same action without AsyncTask thread because my jobSchedulerIntentService have a thread. can i use AsyncTask without thread or i have to use another library ? witch library you can suppose me ? here is my code :

```
MyHttpClient.post("example.com/?", requestParams, new AsyncHttpResponseHandler() {
        @Override
        public void onSuccess(int statusCode, Header[] headers, byte[] responseBody) {
            try {
                JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(new String(responseBody));
                message = jsonObject.getString("user_id"        );
            } catch (JSONException e) {
                Log.i(TAG, "error");
            }
            switch (message){
                case "success_data":{
                    //do something
                    break;
                }
                case "failed_data":
                case "failed_timer":
                default:
                    Log.i(TAG, "error , try again");
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onFailure(int statusCode, Header[] headers, byte[] responseBody, Throwable error) {
            Log.i(TAG, "error"+statusCode);
        }

        @Override
        public void onFinish() {
            super.onFinish();
        }
    });
```

Comment: AsyncTask runs on a seperate thread by default..

Comment: i know , but can any solution by this syntax ?